# Trying using Help and Verbose while parsing command line arguments

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, argparse

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Demo')
parser.add_argument('--verbose',
    action='store_true',
    help='verbose flag' )

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.verbose:
   print("~ Verbose!")
else:
   print("~ Not so verbose")
```

I'm getting this error

> usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--verbose]
>   ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\Sourav\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-c07f728a-968e-40af-b09e-e7d9b67b47fe.json
>
> SystemExit: 2
>
> C:\Users\Sourav\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2855: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
>     warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)

Comment: How are you trying to run this script?  Looks like a Jupyter notebook?  In any case the `sys.argv` list that the parser sees includes this '-f'` argument, which it is not prepared to handle.

Comment: @hpaulj what should I change then?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do!  To test/learn `argparse` don't use a `notebook`.  Run it as an ordinary script from shell.  If you want to set some value in a notebook, don't use `argparse`.

Comment: I tried it using shell too, but couldn't do it.

Comment: Actually, I'm just learning how to use argparse module. Any help would be useful for me.

Comment: I've answered a lot of `argparse` SO questions, usually with test runs.  Sometimes I run the script from a shell, sometimes I create the parser in an Ipython session, and do test runs there, e.g. `args = parse.parse_args(['-v'])`.

Comment: still no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

In a shell window (linux bash):

```
1317:~/mypy$ python stack52235399.py 
~ Not so verbose
0940:~/mypy$ python stack52235399.py --verbose
~ Verbose!
0940:~/mypy$ cat stack52235399.py 
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Demo')
parser.add_argument('--verbose',
    action='store_true',
    help='verbose flag' )

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.verbose:
   print("~ Verbose!")
else:
   print("~ Not so verbose")
```

Comment: Why can't I do it in windows shell?